# How to detect the first and the last argument in the variadic templates?

Tags: c++, arguments, c++11, variadic-templates

How to detect the first and the last argument in the variadic templates?

For the 1st argument it is easy (just compare `sizeof...(T)` with 0), but is there a way to detect the last element?

The example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template < class... T >
struct A
{
    int foo(int k){ return k; };
};

template < class T1, class... T >
struct A< T1, T... >
{
    A() :a()
    {
        std::cout<<"A  i="<<sizeof...(T)<<std::endl
                 <<"   a type = " << typeid(T1).name()<<std::endl;
    }

    int foo(int k){ return anotherA.foo( a.foo(k) ); };

    T1 a;
    A< T... > anotherA;
};

struct B1
{
    B1(){ std::cout<<"b1"<<std::endl; };
    int foo(int k){ std::cout<<"b1::foo() k="<<k<<std::endl; return k+1; };
};
struct B2
{
    B2(){ std::cout<<"b2"<<std::endl; };
    int foo(int k){ std::cout<<"b2::foo() k="<<k<<std::endl; return k+2; };
};
struct B3
{
    B3(){ std::cout<<"b3"<<std::endl; };
    int foo(int k){ std::cout<<"b3::foo() k="<<k<<std::endl; return k+3; };
};

int main ()
{
    A< B3, B2, B1 > a;

    std::cout<<"the value is "
             <<a.foo(5)
             << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'detect'? Do you want to return a value from a tuple-like object at runtime? Evaluate a type at compile-time from a variadic pack?

Comment: @LucDanton In the above example, the constructor A prints i=0 for B1, and i=2 for B3. That means that parameter B1 is the last in the list. Now, is there a way to get total number of arguments passed to A that doesn't change? (in the example, it should be 3)

Comment: In the primary template that number is `sizeof...(T)` and in the specialization it is `1 + sizeof...(T)`. You need to pass that number along to the `anotherA` member of the specialization.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not positive if this is what you want.  But here are two utilities named `first` and `last` that take variadic templates and typedef the first and last type respectively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T1, class ...T>
struct first
{
    typedef T1 type;
};

template <class T1, class ...T>
struct last
{
    typedef typename last<T...>::type type;
};

template <class T1>
struct last<T1>
{
    typedef T1 type;
};

template <class ...T>
struct A
{
    typedef typename first<T...>::type first;
    typedef typename last<T...>::type  last;
};

struct B1 {};
struct B2 {};
struct B3 {};

int main()
{
    typedef A<B1, B2, B3> T;
    std::cout << typeid(T::first).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(T::last).name() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but is enough. Thanks

Comment: The lines like these `typedef typename last<T...>::type type;` , always confuses me due to recursion, is there any easy way to visualize this statement? . Thanks . P.S: sorry if my question seemed stupid :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis:  I like to read a line like that as:  The answer is this meta-function applied to the "rest of the list", where "rest of the list" is defined as the list minus the first element.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another set of code with a convenience function `return_type` that you could use to access any type at a specific index in a varadic template list ... you could then adapt the call to `return_type` so that you get the first and the last arguments (i.e., the first argument will be at 0, and the last argument will be at `sizeof...(TypeList)`):

```
template<typename T>
struct type_id_struct
{
    typedef T type;
    T object_instance;
};

template<int N, typename... TypeList>
struct reduce {};

template<int N, typename T1, typename... TypeList>
struct reduce<N, T1, TypeList...>
{
    typedef typename reduce<N - 1, TypeList... >::type type;
};

template<typename T1, typename... TypeList>
struct reduce<0, T1, TypeList...>
{
    typedef T1 type;
};

//convenience function
template<int N, typename... TypeList>
type_id_struct<typename reduce<N, TypeList...>::type> return_type()
{
        return type_id_struct<typename reduce<N, TypeList...>::type>();
}
```

Here's an example of using the convenience function `return_type` in actual code to determine the Nth template argument in a variadic template:

```
int main()
{
    auto type_returned = return_type<2, int, double, char>();
    std::cout << typeid(type_returned.object_instance).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, since the `int` template argument to `return_type` is `2`, you'll get the `char` type as the output.  Any number over `2` will cause an overflow that will create a compile rather than runtime error.  As noted, you could adapt it so that it's wrapped inside a function in a structure that will allow you to access the types in the variadic template for that specific structure instance using the `sizeof...(TypeList) - 1` applied to an enum.  For instance:

```
template<typename... TypeList>
struct an_object
{
    enum { first = 0, last = (sizeof...(TypeList) - 1) };

    template<int N>
    auto wrapper() -> decltype(return_type<N, TypeList...>())
    {
            return return_type<N, TypeList...>();
    }
};

//...more code

int main()
{
    an_object<int, double, char> a;

    auto r_type1 = a.wrapper<an_object<int, double, char>::first>();
    std::cout << typeid(r_type1.object_instance).name() << std::endl;

    auto r_type2 = a.wrapper<an_object<int, double, char>::last>();
    std::cout << typeid(r_type2.object_instance).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```