# how to return the last type of a variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

For example

```
template<typename... Ts>
LastTypeOfTs f();
```

How to return the last type of a variadic template?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661643/how-to-detect-the-first-and-the-last-argument-in-the-variadic-templates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942322/effective-way-to-select-last-parameter-of-variadic-template

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do a template recursion as below:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct LastTypeOfTs {
   typedef typename LastTypeOfTs<Ts...>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct LastTypeOfTs<T> {
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename... Ts>
typename LastTypeOfTs<Ts...>::type f() {
  //...
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cecd9419a990b93b)