# Remove the last type of a template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use the types of a template parameter pack as parameters to a different template, but cut off the last parameter.

For example:

```
template <class... Ts> struct some_template;

template <class... Ts> struct foo
{
    using bar = some_template<magically_get_all_but_last(Ts)...>;
};

// I might be missing a few "typename"s, but you get the idea.
static_assert(std::is_same<foo<int, bool, std::string>::bar, some_template<int,bool> >::value);
```

Note that this is the opposite of [getting only the last parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088683/how-to-return-the-last-type-of-a-variadic-template).

Comment: the key might be using something like make_index_sequence< sizeof...( Ts ) - 1 >

Comment: @stijn Thanks! I cannot use C++14 yet, but you gave me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt: if you play with parameter packs with C++11 I strongly recommend creating your own version of  `index_sequence` and family!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple approach which use `std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>` together with `std::index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1` to get all but the last type in a list of variadic arguments. Since the parameter pack for the indices is needed, there is an extra indirection which is put into a base but could be anywhere.

```
template <class T, class... Ts> struct foobase;
template <std::size_t... I, class... Ts>
struct foobase<std::index_sequence<I...>, Ts...> {
    using bar = some_template<typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type...>;
};

template <class... Ts> struct foo
    : foobase<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>, Ts...>
{
};
```

Comment: `std::index_sequence` and family can be implemented with C++11. They were just not part of the standard library. So I'd recommend creating your own version. The [proposal n3658](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html) points, e.g., at [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14059084/1120273).

Comment: @tobias note that for extremely long lists, the make index sequence linked is less than ideal: for 10-20ish, it is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution which uses C++11:

```
template <typename ...P>
struct dummy {};

template <template <typename ...> class Obj, typename T, typename ...P>
struct internal;

template <template <typename ...> class Obj, typename ...P1, typename T, typename ...P2>
struct internal<Obj, dummy<P1...>, T, P2...>
{
    using type = typename internal<Obj, dummy<P1..., T>, P2...>::type;
};

template <template <typename ...> class Obj, typename ...P1, typename T, typename L>
struct internal<Obj, dummy<P1...>, T, L>
{
    using type = Obj<P1..., T>;
};

template <template <typename ...> class T, typename ...P>
struct subst_all_but_last
{
    using type = typename internal<T, dummy<>, P...>::type;
};
```

Use like this:

```
using bar = typename subst_all_but_last<some_template, Ts...>::type;
```

instead of

```
using bar = some_template<magically_get_all_but_last(Ts)...>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>

using std::size_t;
using std::tuple;

namespace 
{
    template <class Tuple, template <class...> class Template> struct apply_tuple_params_impl {};
    template <template <class...> class Template, class... Params>
    struct apply_tuple_params_impl<tuple<Params...>, Template>
    {
        typedef Template<Params...> type;
    };

    template <class Param, class Tuple> struct extend_tuple;
    template <class Param, class... Params> struct extend_tuple<Param, tuple<Params...>>
    {
        typedef tuple<Param, Params...> type;
    };

    template <class Param, class... Params> struct all_but_last_type_tuple_impl
    {
        typedef typename extend_tuple<Param, typename all_but_last_type_tuple_impl<Params...>::type>::type type;
    };

    template <class Param> struct all_but_last_type_tuple_impl<Param>
    {
        typedef tuple<> type;
    };
}

// pass the template parameters of a tuple to another template
template <class Tuple, template <class...> class Template>
using apply_tuple_params = typename apply_tuple_params_impl<Tuple, Template>::type;

// a tuple type with all the parameters except the last
template <class... Params>
using all_but_last_type_tuple = typename all_but_last_type_tuple_impl<Params...>::type;
```

And use it like this:

```
template <class... Ts> struct some_template;

template <class... Ts> struct foo
{
    typedef apply_tuple_params<all_but_last_type_tuple<Ts...>, some_template> bar;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<foo<int, bool, std::string>::bar, some_template<int,bool> >::value, "");
```