# Trying to call the first element of a parameter pack as a function and pass the rest of the pack to it as arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have to write a template function with the following interface:

```
template <typename... Args>
void create(Args&&... args)
```

I need to be able to call it like this:

```
create([](int, float){}, 42, 5.f);
```

and I want the function (lambda) to be called with the 2 arguments passed after it. How can I achieve this?

I'm constrained with the interface of `create()` - I cannot separate the function parameter ouf of the parameter pack because of... reasons (just trust me). Perhaps it can be extracted with some tricks like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7664332/3162383) and have the rest of the parameter pack forwarded to it...?

This should work with functions taking an arbitrary number of arguments - not just an int and a float.

Comment: "I cannot separate the function parameter out of the parameter pack because of... reasons" Those reasons better be *very* good, because it really does not make any sense to me why you would constrain yourself like this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on those reasons?  Otherwise `template <typename First, typename... Args> void create(First&& first, Args&&... args)` is how you would normally do it.

Comment: My "reasons" are that I'm reusing a big template machinery and I'm trying to extend it without rewriting it. It is a generic resource manager template class which inherits from a "creator" class which has the ```create()``` method and to it are passed a ```std::string``` (which I have omitted in my question) and a parameter pack. The idea is that a resource manager for a specific type needs the same arguments passed to ```create```, but I want to extend it so ```create``` can behave differently - with different arguments. Not sure if this explains it...

Comment: That doesn't really explain why you can't change the template parameter list - it shouldn't have to match anything else if it just hides a base class template method.

Comment: You can call, from `create()`, a `create2(F func, Args ... args)`?

Comment: Actually here is a [link to my code](https://github.com/onqtam/game/blob/3cfa652e11d20450d28b8b4701715bcdcd7356b5/src/core/GraphicsHelpers.h#L74) - the idea is that ```createCube()``` takes 0 arguments, but ```createGrid()``` may take 5 arguments. I was going to do runtime dispatch based on the string passed to ```create()``` but then it wouldn't compile if I pass a few arguments to ```create()``` because ```createCube()``` takes 0. So my idea is to pass the creator function as well and not do such runtime-string-dispatching. Hope that helps clear things a bit.

Comment: Do your compiler support the upcoming C++17 standard? Then perhaps some creative overloading using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) together with [`std::is_invocable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) for some SFINAE?

Comment: I'm using VS 2017 with ```/std:c++latest``` and gcc/clang with ```-std=c++1z```

Comment: I'll try what @max66 suggests!!!

Comment: Well... my was a question; as suggestion is too obvious. I suppose the answer is "yes".

Comment: @max66 well it worked - this *too obvious* thing was exactly what I needed - thanks! Put it as an answer and I shall accept it. So after all my question had a simple answer and there was no need for downvotes.... oh well :)

Comment: "may take 5 arguments. I was going to do runtime dispatch based on the string passed to create() but then it wouldn't compile if I pass a few arguments to create() because createCube() takes 0. So my idea is to pass the creator function as well and not do such runtime-string-dispatching."  You seem to think that not having a separete arg from the pack will prevent compile time errors.  Your problem is, I cannot think of a situation where `template<class F, class...Args> void create` would break while `template<class...Args> void create` that invokes the first arg won't.  Please clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In c++ 11, how to invoke an arbitrary callable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918679/in-c-11-how-to-invoke-an-arbitrary-callable-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This should work with functions taking an arbitrary number of arguments - not just an int and a float.

In C++14 you can unpack them by means of a generic lambda invoked in-place and to which you forward your arguments.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<utility>

template <typename... Args>
void create(Args&&... args) {
    [](auto &&f, auto&&... p){
        std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(std::forward<decltype(p)>(p)...);
    }(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    create([](int, float){}, 42, 5.f);
}
```

In C++11 you can use another function template or an equivalent functor that does the same job, then use them instead of the generic lambda.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<utility>

struct Functor {
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    static void invoke(F &&f, Args&&... args) {
        std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename... Args>
void create(Args&&... args) {
    Functor::invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    create([](int, float){}, 42, 5.f);
}
```

Comment: Why do you forward the function inside of invoke and the lambda? Seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: @MillieSmith As long as you use only lambdas it's unnecessary. Anyway the function accepts also functors. If you have a functor with a reference specifier on the `operator()`, things can vary if you forward `f` or not.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. At your disposal for any other question.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is demand the execution to an helper function without signature limitations.

By example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename L, typename ... Args>
void create_helper (L const & l, Args && ... args)
 { (void)l(args...); }

template <typename ... Args>
void create (Args && ... args)
 { create_helper(args...); }

int main()
 {
   create([](int i, float f){ std::cout << i << ", " << f << std::endl; },
          42, 5.f);
 }
```

Comment: Why `(void)`?  It seems vacuously in usefulness here.

Comment: @Yakk - fear; only and simple fear; since when you showed me the comma-hijack trick, I'm afraid of not-void disabled values returned by generic functions :(

Comment: You should at least forward arguments using `std::forward` within `create`.

Comment: @skypjack - within `create()`?  Or within `create_helper()`? Sorry but I have a lot of problems using correctly references.

Comment: @max66 Actually both of them. See my answer.